# Sorting Gmail contacts by date

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, sorting

Is it possible to sort Gmail contacts by date?

I want to see the last contacts added and couldn't find a way to do this. The only option I see is by first and last name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`goobook`](https://gitlab.com/goobook/goobook) command line tool for accessing Google Contacts has a subcommand called dump_contacts. This returns a dump of your entire address book in an XML based format. Each entry has timestamp details for the last update and last edit. You can use these values to sort the entries by date.

---

<strike>Using [Google command line tools](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) seems to return results in order of filing if no other sort method is set.</strike> **Edit:** As others have noted the `googlectl` tool is obsolete.

Comment: Interesting... I forgot about the command lines..!

Comment: I doubt this is a desirable solution for somebody asking on a web apps site about their gmail interface, but it's interesting that direct calls to their API does return the records in what seems to be the order entered. Personally I think adding this to the web interface would be a clutter-feature. It's not usually valuable user-facing data.

Comment: **"8 June 2015: GoogleCL is currently broken due to the OAuth1 turndown, and likely to remain so. Thanks for your support over the years, and apologies for the lack of prior notice."**

Comment: @ale I just edited this with an alternative that does work. Slightly more involved for this use case because you have to parse the output, but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

They are not providing this information to the public, hence you can't really do much about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information quickly (if, say, you want to find contacts you just recently created) with the OAuth 2 Playground.

1. Sign in here: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
2. Use a `GET` URL like this to list your contacts starting with most recently modified:

> https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=25&start-index=1&orderby=lastmodified&sortorder=descending

([Original source](https://qr.ae/pGuKfU))